# Java convert .docx to pdf with Apache POI get OutOfMemory exception

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi, xwpf

I'm trying to convert a .docx file to pdf with Apache POI. I read several question about that in StackOverflow but I didn't see anyone having my issue.

I'm using this method to convert Ms docx to pdf:

```
private void thumbForDoc(File file) {
        String fullPath = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(file);
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();

            File destFile = new File(fullPath + fileName + ".pdf");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn(String.format("Error trying to create the thumbnail for the file %s", file.getAbsolutePath()), e);
        }
    }
```

This is the relevant part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Unfortunaly the conversion doesn't happen and, after a while, I've an OutOfMemory exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: null
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:95) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.write(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPages.addPage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.add(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at com.lowagie.text.Document.add(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js6.jar:?]
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension.ExtendedDocument.add(ExtendedDocument.java:114) ~[fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.elements.StylableDocument.flushTable(StylableDocument.java:345) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.elements.StylableDocument.pageBreak(StylableDocument.java:128) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.elements.StylableDocument.columnBreak(StylableDocument.java:107) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.elements.StylableDocument.simulateText(StylableDocument.java:211) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.elements.StylableDocument.addElement(StylableDocument.java:94) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.endVisitParagraph(PdfMapper.java:409) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.endVisitParagraph(PdfMapper.java:111) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitParagraph(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:333) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitBodyElements(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:247) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.start(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:199) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:56) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at server.storage.ThumbnailGenerator.thumbForDoc(ThumbnailGenerator.java:158) ~[classes/:?]
    at server.storage.ThumbnailGenerator.createThumbnail(ThumbnailGenerator.java:81) ~[classes/:?]
    at server.storage.ThumbnailGenerator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6fd76f41.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextCallable.call(DelegatingSecurityContextCallable.java:86) [spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

I'm quite confused. In fact I downgraded Apache POI to 3.15 because seems 3.17 incompatible with xwpf.
Furthemore, the final result changes changing version of libraries. In some cases I was able to generate the PDF but it was broken and the size was bigger than 400MB!!

Some advice would be appreciate.

====================================================

These are my dependencies:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testapp 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ testapp-server ---
[INFO] it.testapp:testapp-server:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.23.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.6.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:2.6.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.26-incubating:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mobile:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.mobile:spring-mobile-device:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-data:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.6:runtime
[INFO] +- org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-core:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |     \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers:jar:1.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-data-rest:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:jar:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.16:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:57.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.javers:javers-core:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.github.lukehutch:fast-classpath-scanner:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- net.coobird:thumbnailator:jar:0.4.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-debugger:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.levigo.jbig2:levigo-jbig2-imageio:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-jpeg2000:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.334 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-20T09:47:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/619M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am also confused. Your pom says iText 5.5.12 but your error says iText 2.1.7. There is a Maven command to show your entire pom dependency tree.

Comment: Oh I already see where it comes from, xdocreport.

Comment: I should probably stop looking at Stack Overflow, because I always get depressed when I see my name still being used in code. Why are people still using that old version?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm sorry you are getting depressed! Unfortunately it's not my fault. I need xwpf to convert .doc to .pdf and that library is using iText 2.1.7 internally. Seems I can't use a more updated library. It's for that I'm looking for suggestion to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @drenda execute this command, then add the output to your question: `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse done